# Duplicate key during import in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, psql

I am following an PostgreSQL book, and had to import a CSV file into a table `census.lu_tracts`.

**Problem:** When performing the `INSERT` query as shown below, I get the error:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_lu_tracts"
DETAIL:  Key (tract_id)=(25001010800) already exists.
```

How did the key becomes duplicate? `SELECT * from lu_tracs` shows 0 rows.

```
CREATE SCHEMA census;
set search_path=census;
CREATE TABLE lu_tracts(tract_id varchar(11), tract_long_id varchar(25)
, tract_name varchar(150)
, CONSTRAINT pk_lu_tracts PRIMARY KEY (tract_id));

INSERT INTO lu_tracts( tract_id, tract_long_id, tract_name)
SELECT geo_id2, geo_id, geo_display
FROM staging.factfinder_import
WHERE geo_id2 ~ '^[0-9]+';
```

Comment: The transaction was aborted, so no rows were inserted - and why you see 0 rows in that table. You most likely have a duplicate in the `staging.factfiner_import` table where `geo_id2` = `25001010800`. You might try using `SELECT DISTINCT` which might fix it. Otherwise, you'd need to filter it out another way.

Comment: `DISTINCT ON (geo_id2)` probably will be better than just `DISTINCT`.

Comment: `DISTINCT ON (geoid2)` works :)

Comment: Could you please post this as an answer?  I would be happy to upvote (so as to mark this closed).

Comment: @JakubKania I will mark it as the selected answer too

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is `DISTINCT ON (geo_id2)` which will select only one row per geo_id2 (more in the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)), it should be accompanied by an ORDER BY clause that will specify what row will be choosen.